# wxpython httplib with proxy shows 400 bad request

Tags: python, wxpython, httplib

Took a look at the other threads but couldn't build anything from it.

I have a list of URL's which I'm trying to get the HEAD status of and check before further manipulation. My current code with httplib works fine (else part), however I need to ensure the code works from behind a proxy, this is where I'm having trouble.

The code works and produces an output (if part), but the output status from the URLs is "400 bad request" which seems to be its not being proxied correctly.

```
dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Are you connected to a proxy?", "LAN check", wx.YES | wx.NO | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
        self.urlFld.SetValue("")
        for line in self.myList:
            url = urlparse.urlparse(line)
            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("myproxy.com", 8080)
            conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
            r1 = conn.getresponse()
            r1 = r1.status, r1.reason
            r1 = str(r1)
            self.urlFld.AppendText(url.scheme + "://" + url.hostname + url.path + "\t\t\t" + r1 + "\r")
    else:
        self.urlFld.SetValue("")
        for line in self.myList:
                url = urlparse.urlparse(line)
                conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.hostname)
                conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
                r1 = conn.getresponse()
                r1 = r1.status, r1.reason
                r1 = str(r1)
                self.urlFld.AppendText(url.scheme + "://" + url.hostname + url.path + "\t\t\t" + r1 + "\r")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, if you're using a proxy server, you have to pass the full URL to the `HEAD` method...

```
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
    self.urlFld.SetValue("")
    for line in self.myList:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("myproxy.com", 8080)
        conn.request("HEAD", line)
        r1 = conn.getresponse()
```

...otherwise it has no way of knowing which host to connect to.

Comment: must get tired of helping me! It worked however! thanks again, much appreciated. Only issues now (not a massive one) was that the https://www.facebook.com URL in myList (https) return a 400 bad request still ,everything else was fine. what's your thinking on this issue, not to fix im just interested in trying to understand it

Comment: @directpixel It's possible that the problem with `https://www.facebook.com` is that it's a secure (HTTPS) page, and your proxy is being not being accessed via a secure connection. You might be able to reconfigure the proxy to allow it, or you could just change the URL to `http://www.facebook.com` so you're accessing it via a non-secure URL.